# Problema diagonales de matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x

compañeros me podrían ayudar con este código necesito imprimir las dos diagonales de una matriz y el problema es que solo me imprime la diagonal principal (la que empieza desde la esquina izquierda)

try:

```
matriz=[]
matriz2=[]
longitud=3

for a in range(3):
    fila=[]
    for b in range(3):
        numeros=int(input("Digite un numero para la primera lista: "))
        fila.append(numeros)
    matriz.append(fila)

diagonal_secundaria=[]
for e in range(len(matriz)):
    for g in range(len(matriz)):
        numero=matriz[e][g]

        if [e]+[g]==longitud-1:
            diagonal_secundaria.append(numero)

diagonal_primaria=[]
for h in range(len(matriz)):
    for k in range(len(matriz)):
        numero2=matriz[h][k]

        if [h]==[k]:
            diagonal_primaria.append(numero2)


print(diagonal_secundaria)
print(diagonal_primaria)
```

except ValueError:
    print("El valor digitado debe ser numerico")

Comment: Tienes lo que parece ser un error tipográfico en `if [e]+[g]==longitud-1` debiera ser en todo caso `if e+g==longitud-1`

Comment: muchas gracias medio dia tratando de buscar el error y era una cosa tan simple como esa